# JavaScript time greeting?

Tags: javascript

How do you make something with JavaScript that when your time is below 12 o'clock, it says "good morning!" and when it is after 12 o'clock, it says "good afternoon!"?

Comment: School project by any chance?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here it is!

```js
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getHours();

if (time < 12) {
  document.write("<b>Good morning!</b>");
}
if (time > 12) {
  document.write("<b>Good afternoon!</b>");
}
if (time == 12) {
  document.write("<b>Go eat lunch!</b>");
}
```

Comment: Remember that < means less than and > means greater than.

Comment: What, just because its between 12:00 and 12:59, I get *no* greeting whatsoever. How rude!

Comment: What about at noon? What does it say then?

Comment: @deceze: The odds of someone looking at it at that exact time is very low.

Comment: One whole hour each day are low odds?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it would be down to minutes, now it says "Go eat lunch!"

Answer (score 4):

```
const date = new Date;
let hours = date.getHours();
let status = (hours < 12)? "Morning" :
             ((hours <= 18 && hours >= 12 ) ? "Afternoon" : "Night");
console.log(status);
```

Answer (score 2):

**The following should work:**

```
var hours = new Date().hours;

if(hours > 12){
     alert("Good Afternoon!");   
}
else{
     alert("Good Morning!");   
}
```

**Just for fun, here's a one liner:**

```
(new Date().hours > 12) ? alert("Good Afternoon!") : alert("Good Morning!");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/RY5ne/)**

Comment: I believe `.hours` should be `.getHours()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("<h2>");
      var day = new Date();
      var hr = day.getHours();
      if (hr >= 4 && hr < 12) {
          document.write("Goedenmorgen");
      } else if (hr == 12) {
          document.write("Goedemiddag");
      } else if (hr >= 12 && hr <= 16) {
          document.write("Goedemiddag");
      } else if (hr >= 16 && hr <= 23) {
          document.write("Goedenavond");
      } else {
          document.write("Goedennacht");
      }
      document.write("</h2>");
  </script>
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but rather add a little textual explanation about why and how your approach works and how it differs from the other answers given.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
currentTime=new Date();
//getHour() function will retrieve the hour from current time
if(currentTime.getHours()<12)
document.write("<b>Good Morning!! </b>");
else if(currentTime.getHours()<17)
document.write("<b>Good Afternoon!! </b>");
else 
document.write("<b>Good Evening!! </b>");
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the answer with some explanation of how and why this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

```
//if hour is between 6am-12pm ,print good morning
//if hour is between 12pm-6pm ,print good afternoon
//else good evening
let hour = 5;
if(hour>=6 && hour<12) {
    console.log('Good Morning')
}

else if(hour>+12 && hour<18) {
    console.log('Good Afternoon')
}

else {
    console.log('Good Evening')
}
```

Comment: I think you need to convert time in 24 hour format, then you can compare time-hour component.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```js
const getGreeting = () => {
    const currentTime = +dayjs().format('HH')
    // var hours = new Date().hours  // or with Vanilla JavaScript, hours in 24

    if (currentTime >= 6 && currentTime < 12) {
      return "Good morning"
    } else if (currentTime >= 12 && currentTime < 18) {
      return "Good afternoon"
    } else if (currentTime >= 18 && currentTime < 22) {
      return "Good evening"
    } else {
      return "Good night"
    }
  }
```