# Display greeting (morning/afternoon/evening) using both hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write an HTML document that displays a greeting to visitors, like "Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening!"
But I don't know how to use both `hours` and `minutes` together:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>ITP1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <label id="TIME"></label>
</body>

<script>
    var myDate = new Date();
    var hrs = myDate.getHours();
    var mins = date.getMinutes();
    var greet;

    if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 11.59)
        greet = 'Good Morning';
    else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17)
        greet = 'Good Afternoon';
    else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24)
        greet = 'Good Evening';

    document.getElementById('TIME').innerHTML =
        '<b>' + greet;
</script>

</html>
```

I want to set ranges for morning/evening/afternoon using both hours and minutes with these ranges:

- Evening: 0:00 to 5:29
- Morning: 5:30 to 11:59
- Afternoon: 12:00 to 17:59
- Evening: 18:00 to 24:00

Comment: `hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 11.59` is mathematically impossible. You already have the concept of chaining two conditionals together with `&&` - have you tried using the `mins` variable at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122543/javascript-time-greeting/7122565

Comment: @Caspera no, my question is about how to use both hours and mins not just hours, that's what i did above

Comment: The console errors told me that you have an undefined variable. This line: `var mins = date.getMinutes();` should be `var mins = myDate.getMinutes();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change `date.getMinutes()` to `myDate.getMinutes()`.

Then, you can compare them like this:

```js
if (hrs >= 5 && ((hrs == 5 && mins >= 30) || (hrs > 5 && hrs < 12)))
  greet = 'Good Morning';
else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs < 18)
  greet = 'Good Afternoon';
else if ((hrs >= 18 && hrs < 24) || hrs > 0)
  greet = 'Good Evening';
else
  greet = 'Error';
```

Note that I added an else at the end for weird cases.

The snippet below shows this in action. Don't worry about the other code; it's just there to make the tests output readable.

```js
function doATest(timeIn) {
  var myDate = new Date(timeIn ? "0 " + timeIn : null);
  var hrs = myDate.getHours();
  var mins = myDate.getMinutes(); // changed date to myDate
  var greet;

  //   morning |  5:30-11:59
  // afternoon | 12:00-17:59
  //   evening | 18:00-05:29
  if (hrs >= 5 && ((hrs == 5 && mins >= 30) || (hrs > 5 && hrs < 12)))
    greet = 'Good Morning';
  else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs < 18)
    greet = 'Good Afternoon';
  else if ((hrs >= 18 && hrs < 24) || hrs > 0)
    greet = 'Good Evening';
  else
    greet = 'Error';

  document.getElementById('timeTable').innerHTML +=
    '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + (timeIn ? timeIn : "Right Now") + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + greet + '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
}

doATest("1:00");
doATest("1:37");
doATest("5:00");
doATest("5:15");
doATest("5:29");
doATest("5:29:59");
doATest("5:30");
doATest("5:45");
doATest("6:00");
doATest("6:15");
doATest("6:30");
doATest("6:45");
doATest("6:45");
doATest("7:00");
doATest("waffles"); // not valid
doATest("9:45");
doATest("11:00");
doATest("11:30");
doATest("11:45");
doATest("11:59");
doATest("11:59:59");
doATest("12:00");
doATest("12:34");
doATest("12:48");
doATest("13:00");
doATest("13:57");
doATest("15:00");
doATest("17:00");
doATest("17:20");
doATest("17:40");
doATest("17:59");
doATest("17:59:59.999");
doATest("18:00");
doATest("17:76"); // not valid
doATest("18:36");
doATest("18:63"); // not valid
doATest("19:00");
doATest("20:00");
doATest("23:00");
doATest("24:00"); // really 0:00 the next day
doATest("27:00"); // not valid
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>ITP1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Greeting</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="timeTable"></tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much and that's exactly what I was confused.